# ScrollBy() scrolling over the maximum

Tags: android

Due to Android not allowing me to just let it handle scrolling on a TextView (link to that question to be added as soon as I write it) I need to handle it myself. The code i am using is quite simple, and it works to an extent, with a problem, it just keeps scrolling after the maximum (wether that is the top or the bottom). I found using canScrollVertically(direction) works, but that limits me to API lvl 14 and above, which is something i dont want to do. Here is my current code:

```
float prevY;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        int dy = (int) (prevY - event.getY());
        if (myView.canScrollVertically(dy)) { //This is the line i want to get rid of
            myView.scrollBy(0, dy);
        }
    }
    prevY = event.getY();

    return true;
}
```

Also, is there any way of making it behave completelly like any Scrolling view? I mean when you swipe quickly and let go, it doesent sto inmediatly, it keeps the speed for a while, so scrolling long distances doesent take ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from David's answer, and a lot of trial and error, here is a version that doesent allow scrolling past the top and bottom, and works from the onTouch() I alredy have.

```
float prevY;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        int dy = (int) (prevY - event.getY());
        if (dy < 0) {
            int distanceToTop = myView.getScrollY();
            if (-distanceToTop < dy) {
                myView.scrollBy(0, dy);
            } else {
                myView.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        } else {
            int realHeight = (myView.getLineCount() + 1)
                    * myView.getLineHeight();
            int distanceToBottom = myView.getScrollY() - realHeight
                    + myView.getHeight();
            if (-distanceToBottom > dy) {
                myView.scrollBy(0, dy);
            } else {
                myView.scrollTo(0, realHeight - myView.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }
    prevY = event.getY();
    return true;
}
```

Note that i allow scrolling to one line further than the maximum to let some space from the bottom of the view to the bottom line.

It is however not what a normal scrolling view does, as it doesent keep scrolling when a swipe is performed, but it is good enough for me if no other answer allows me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  @Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()+view.getTop()));// Calculate the scrolldiff
        if( diff == 0 ){  //  the bottom has been reached
            Log.d(ScrollTest.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached" );
        }
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}
```